# Is it necessary to add same domain name in SPF records itself?

Tags: networking, dns, system-administration, spf

I have a mail server `mserver.com`  
But I am confused which one to use

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
or
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:mserver.com ~all
```

Can I use same domain in SPF record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the domain using `include:` in its own SPF record is not correct because it creates a loop.  If you want to authorize your own server to send mail under that domain, you need to identify it either by its IP address (`a:server.example.com`) or by the domain's MX record (`mx:example.com`; if they point to your mail server).